# android How to send POST json request to Laravel Framework

Tags: php, android, laravel

Hi im doing both android and laravel framework..
but when i do post method and send json to laravel api via POST.. it will give a 500 result.. please help..

this is one of my asynctask in android sending the post data.. assume sendJsonObj is a jsonobject with values..

```
URL url = new URL("http://dexter-laravelframe.rhcloud.com/register");

        urlConnect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnect.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnect.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        urlConnect.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnect.setRequestProperty("x-csrf-token", Model_Application.token_csrf);
        urlConnect.connect();

        OutputStreamWriter outWrite = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnect.getOutputStream());
        outWrite.write(sendJsonObj.toString());
        outWrite.flush();
        outWrite.close();

        int code = urlConnect.getResponseCode();`
```

on my Laravel framework..
   routes.php
`Route::post('/register', 'UserController@register');`

UserController.php

```
public function register()
{
    $json = Input::json()->all();

    $resultJson = json_encode($json);

    echo $resultJson;

}
```

this will give a 500 response code from Laravel api.. i want it to read the json data.. and send it back..  if i used Mozilla plugin rest client, and send the json data in body.. it gives 200..

Comment: 500 is internal server error, so you should have the error logged somewhere (I am not familiar with Laravel).

Comment: It would be `app/storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: Which version or Laravel are you using?  That syntax doesn't look right at all.  what happens if you just do `return Response::json(Input::all());`

Comment: If you use Laravel 5, check what does Handler::render get before dispatching the exception. Could it be a CORS issue?

Comment: Use Volley  as the HTTP handler and jsonObject. In contrast, use Route:post via api in laravel. checkout:
https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple